# RSpec ruby parameter

Tags: arrays, ruby, rspec, parameters

```
describe Array do
  describe "#sum" do
    it "has a #sum method" do
      expect([]).to respond_to(:sum)
    end

    it "should be 0 for an empty array" do
      expect([].sum).to eq(0)
    end

    it "should add all of the elements" do
      expect([1,2,4].sum).to eq(7)
    end
  end
end
```

The code above is Rspec code. I need ruby code to be tested by the RSpec above, and I thought I need to make 'class Array' and the class gets parameter either array or text (like [].sum) .

```
class Array

        def initialize(arr)
            @arr = arr    
        end

        def sum
            if @arr == nil
                return 0
            else

                if @arr.include?(.)

                else

                end    
            end
        end
    end
```

but then I realized that I got wrong idea about the parameter.  I've searched over hours about RSpec to figure out what that means.. ([].sum as parameter) but I failed.

Comment: you do not need to create a class because `Array` class is already there.

Comment: I see. then what else can I try? should I make 'sum' method? I don't understand what method or class I should make..TT

Comment: Your code in Rspec will just pass if you run it. Either you misunderstood the task or the task is senseless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with RSpec, but more with the **subject** itself, in this case the `Array` class.

To make your tests pass you're expected to "monkey patch" that said `Array` to add the instance method `sum`, something like this:

```
class Array
  def sum
    return 0 if empty?

    sum = 0
    self.each { |val| sum += val.to_i }
    sum
  end
end
```

**EDIT**

Please notice that Ruby 2.4 already includes a `sum` method, so the code above is for previous 2.x versions https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Array.html#method-i-sum

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can use rspec's implicitly-defined subject.  As the [documentation](http://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/3-5/docs/subject/implicitly-defined-subject) indicates:

> If the first argument to the outermost example group is a class, an
>   instance of that class is exposed to each example via the subject
>   method.

Using their first example as a template:

```
RSpec.describe Array do
  it "should be empty when first created" do
    expect(subject).to be_empty
  end
end
```

You can update your examples to use an implicit subject.  For example:

```
RSpec.describe Array do
  describe "#sum" do
    it "has a #sum method" do
      expect(subject).to respond_to(:sum)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: sadly.. I can't change the RSpec test code. it's given as the test, and I have to fit to that. thank you though! I vote for you.